# How to I check if a sequence is a protein sequence or not?

Tags: python, biopython

Given a random sequence, how can I check if that sequence is protein or not?

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
my_prot = Seq("'TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR")
my_prot


my_prot.alphabet #How to make a check here ??
```

Comment: Do you mind specifying the protein string pattern?

Comment: you would have to have a set of criteria by which to judge it .... theres no magic for it

Comment: I was expecting any in-built method.

Comment: We're not biologists.

Comment: If it is built-in you will find it in the API docs: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/

Comment: ImportError: Bio.Alphabet has been removed from Biopython. In many cases, the alphabet can simply be ignored and removed from scripts. In a few cases, you may need to specify the ``molecule_type`` as an annotation on a SeqRecord for your script to work correctly. Please see https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet for more information.

Comment: @YS-L possibly neither are you an artist, or a musician, or a chemist, or a farmer - but increasingly [artists](https://openai.com/dall-e-2/) and [musicians](https://sonic-pi.net/) and [chemists](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Chemistry_software) and [farmers](https://www.wired.com/story/john-deere-tractor-jailbreak-defcon-2022/) and even [biologists](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_genomics) are (of necessity) becoming programmers.  Probably you're going to have to learn to live with that/them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `Seq` object has an assigned alphabet, you can check if that alphabet is a protein alphabet:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC, ProteinAlphabet
my_prot = Seq("TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR", alphabet=IUPAC.IUPACProtein())

print isinstance(my_prot.alphabet, ProteinAlphabet)
```

However, if you don't have the alphabet known, you'll have to employ some heuristics to guess whether or not it's a protein sequence. This could be as easy as checking if the sequence is entirely "ATC[GU]", or if it employs other letter codes.

But this isn't perfect. For instance, the sequence "ATCG" could be alanine, threonine, cysteine, glycine (i.e. a protein), or it could be adenine, thymine, cytosine, guanine (DNA). Similarly, "ACG" could be a protein, RNA, or DNA. It's technically impossible to be sure that a sequence is DNA, and not a protein sequence. However, if you have a `SeqRecord` or other context for the `Seq`, you may be able to check if it's a protein sequence.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I am aware of the ambiguity problem. But for my case, this will work fine.

Comment: It did not work when using an adapted script. The substitution of the sequence "TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR" (i.e. to a sys.argv[1] element), it returned 'True' instead of the input be "TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR2222222".

Comment: ImportError: Bio.Alphabet has been removed from Biopython. In many cases, the alphabet can simply be ignored and removed from scripts. In a few cases, you may need to specify the ``molecule_type`` as an annotation on a SeqRecord for your script to work correctly. Please see https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Biopython removed Bio.Alphabet

copying from https://www.biostars.org/p/102/

You can use:

```
import re

from Bio.Seq import Seq

def validate(seq, alphabet='dna'):
    
    alphabets = {'dna': re.compile('^[acgtn]*$', re.I), 
             'protein': re.compile('^[acdefghiklmnpqrstvwy]*$', re.I)}


    if alphabets[alphabet].search(seq) is not None:
         return True
    else:
         return False



dataz = 'AAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDRRRRRRRREERRRRGGG'

pippo = Seq(dataz)

print(pippo, type(pippo))

print(validate(str(pippo), 'dna'))

print(validate(str(pippo), 'protein'))

dataz = 'atg'

pippo = Seq(dataz)

print(pippo, type(pippo))

print(validate(str(pippo), 'dna'))

print(validate(str(pippo), 'protein'))
```

output:

```
AAAAAAACCCCCCCCCCCCCCDDDDDDRRRRRRRREERRRRGGG <class 'Bio.Seq.Seq'>
False
True
atg <class 'Bio.Seq.Seq'>
True
True
```