# Validate protein sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

In some cases, I have sequences with characters that do not corresponds to proteins.

```
>ISAnsp8_orf1
MRKSRFTEEQIAHALRQVDAGVPAAELCRKLGISEQTFYAWKKKYAGMGIAEMRRVKQLEDENRRLKTLVADLTLDKHMLQEVLRKKF
>IS3_orf1
UGAAGAGCUGGCUAUCCUCCAAAAGGCCGCGACAUACUUCGCGAAGCGCC
>IS3_orf2
..............................(((((((((((......[[[
>IS3_orf3
UGAAAUGAAGUAUGUCUUUAUUGAAAAACAUCAGGCUGAGUUCAGCAUCA
>IS3_orf4
[[[..)))))))))))..............]]]]]]
>IS3_orf5
AAGCAAUGUGCCGCGUGCUCCGGGUGGCCCGCA
>IS3_orf7
MTKTVSTSKKPRKQHSPEFRSEALKLAERIGVTAAARELSLYESQLYNWRSKQQNQQTSSERELEMSTEIARLKRQLAERDEELAILQKAATYFAKRLK
```

Because I want to validate the sequences before to save in another file, I wrote this to test a validation method. That is rare because I used to different sequences, one including non-protein characters '(' but it still gives me the answer as True.

Testing all the three possibilities to 'sequence'the answer is the same (False)

```
import sys
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC, ProteinAlphabet

sequence = sys.argv[1]
#sequence = '((((((((((('
#sequence = 'TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR'

my_prot = Seq(sequence, alphabet=IUPAC.IUPACProtein)

print isinstance(my_prot.alphabet, ProteinAlphabet)     

if isinstance(my_prot.alphabet, ProteinAlphabet) == True:
  print 'ok' , isinstance(my_prot.alphabet, ProteinAlphabet)
else:
  print 'no'
```

Comment: ImportError: Bio.Alphabet has been removed from Biopython.
In many cases, the alphabet can simply be ignored and removed from scripts. 
In a few cases, you may need to specify the ``molecule_type`` as an 
annotation on a SeqRecord for your script to work correctly.
 Please see https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to I check if a sequence is a protein sequence or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609380/how-to-i-check-if-a-sequence-is-a-protein-sequence-or-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Biopython currently does not provide alphabet validation when you initiate a `Seq` or similar object (the main reasons for this is the large performance cost). There is a lot discussion surrounding this and the situation may change in the future; in fact the first Biopython Enhancement Proposal (BEP) is about the use of alphabets in Biopython.

Anyway, to solve your issue for now, there is a `_verify_alphabet` function buried in Biopython, although it's 'private', I see no reason not to use it:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC, _verify_alphabet

sequences = ['TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR', '(((((((((((']

for sequence in sequences:
    my_prot = Seq(sequence, IUPAC.protein)
    print(my_prot, _verify_alphabet(my_prot))
```

Output (in Python 3.6 with Bio version 1.73dev):

```
TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR True
((((((((((( False
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for sharing. Can you please explain, based on what the validity of a sequence is considered? Thanks

Comment: @Chris_Rands , thanks for sharing. Can you please explain, based on what the validity of a sequence is considered? Thanks

Comment: ImportError: Bio.Alphabet has been removed from Biopython.
In many cases, the alphabet can simply be ignored and removed from scripts. 
In a few cases, you may need to specify the ``molecule_type`` as an 
annotation on a SeqRecord for your script to work correctly.
 Please see https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Biopython removed Bio.Alphabet

copying from https://www.biostars.org/p/102/

You can use:

```
import re

def validate(seq, alphabet='dna'):
    
    alphabets = {'dna': re.compile('^[acgtn]*$', re.I), 
             'protein': re.compile('^[acdefghiklmnpqrstvwy]*$', re.I)}


    if alphabets[alphabet].search(seq) is not None:
         return True
    else:
         return False


sequences = ['TGEKPYVCQECGKAFNCSSYLSKHQR', '(((((((((((']

for sequence in sequences:
    
    print(validate(sequence, 'protein'))
```

output:

```
True
False
```