# Python script won't handle non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I'm trying to do some machine learning learning on a sequencing dataset that involves special characters and Greek alphabet. and it keeps throwing errors. Every single time I run the script it throws an error from different position.

```
file = open(filename,encoding="utf-8")
for record in SeqIO.parse(file,"fasta"):
        print("ID %s" % record.id)
        print("Sequence length %i" % len(record))
```

---

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0394' in position 2635: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Hi. It looks like you're using the now defunct python2? python3 uses utf-8 by default

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.12

Comment: And where is the "Δ" character? If it's in the description, then there is no problem. If it's in the sequence, then the library doesn't support non-ASCII characters.

Comment: I get UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 61-63: ordinal not in range(128) for Δ in sequence, no prob in ID

Comment: Bio/Seq.py line 1725 : self._data = bytes(data, encoding="ASCII")

Answer (score 1):

line 1725 Bio/Seq.py

```
....
   self._data = self._data = bytes(data, encoding="ASCII")
....
```

giving:

```
data ='\u0394'

data = bytes(data, encoding="ASCII")

print(data.decode())
```

output:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0394' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

else:

```
data ='\u0394'

data = bytes(data, encoding="utf-8")

print(data.decode())
```

output:

```
Δ
```

I guess

> library doesn't support non-ASCII characters

for the sequences as pointed out by @gre_gor

Comment: I'm using BioPython! Which as you said seems not to be having support for UTF-8 encoding. So any other way to work around this issue??

Comment: I wish I could help you with that, was trying to increase my points, class Seq(_SeqAbstractBaseClass): --->  class _SeqAbstractBaseClass(ABC) my knowledge stops after 'search text', try posting it on Bioinformatics stack or Biostars maybe somebody else has your problem too, PS change the title to something like Biopython SeqIO script so that could be easier to spot by the experts

Comment: @FaisalManjahy Hi Faisal, just out of curiosity I changed all the references to "ASCII" to "utf-8" in Bio/Seq.py, I can actually read with SeqIO.parse and pritn(record.seq)  of sequence like 'GGGTTTGGGΔΔΔAAAA'. I am not sure about what I messed up with this, probably complement,reverse translate etc methods will throw errors ?! dont know but remember this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962651/validate-protein-sequence : see below

Comment: "Biopython currently does not provide alphabet validation when you initiate a Seq or similar object (the main reasons for this is the large performance cost). There is a lot discussion surrounding this and the situation may change in the future; in fact the first Biopython Enhancement Proposal (BEP) is about the use of alphabets in Biopython........"

Comment: https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet ; This page is intended to help people updating existing code using Biopython to cope with the removal of the Bio.Alphabet module in Biopython 1.78 (September 2020).